# Returning lost reputation after removal of downvoted question or answer.

Tags: feature-request, reputation, deleted-questions

I noticed that today my reptutation was lower than it was yesterday. As a result of a user removing his or her account, I had lost some reputation. This got me looking at my reputation history. Apparently reputation gained on a question is lost once the question is removed, and yes, I've noticed that this is already a topic of discussion here on meta.

What surprised me is that reputation *lost* by downvoting a question (or answer) is not regained once the question (or answer) is removed. For example on [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753437/why-must-a-field-with-a-cyclic-group-of-units-be-finite/838275#838275) [three](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840980/how-can-i-solve-this-equation-e2x3-6x2-3-0/840993#840993) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810936/it-takes-72hours-for-five-workers-to-paint-an-office-building/810939#810939). Of course there is not much to see here (unless you are a moderator perhaps?) as the questions and answers in question have been removed. So in brief, my question is:

> Why do I lose all reputation *gained* on a question once it is removed, but do I not regain all reputation *lost* on a question once it is removed?

In fear of insulting anyone who chose to implement this after deep consideration, I've tagged my question [feature-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) and not [bug](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug); is it desirable to change this?

Comment: Note that reputation changes from downvoting (and the removal of said downvotes) do not appear in your reputation history.

Answer (score 9):

This is already the case, if you downvoted a post and that post gets deleted, you get the 1 reputation point you spent for downvoting back.

What is probably confusing you is that you don't lose any reputation for downvoting a question, this only happens for downvoting answers.